# How to add additional column to Django QuerySet

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I have a QuerySet with Books and I would like to add a `score` field to every Book result.

```
qs = Book.objects.all()
```

In raw SQL I would write:

```
SELECT
    *,
    (
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE value=1 AND book=b.id) - 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE value=-1 AND book=b.id)
    ) AS score
FROM
    Book b;
```

How can I achieve it in Django? I tried `annotate()`, but it seems it's not meant for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Use an [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses) or `extra` with `select` (and use google more carefully before asking a question here).

Comment: have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations

Comment: There is no single page in google that describes what I want. I've read everything about `annotate` and `extra` in docs. It doesn't say a word about this. If you've managed to find anything useful, please share a link.

Comment: @ambi How is filtering any help here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If votes possible values are only 1 and -1 you can just sum them using mentioned [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses): `Book.objects.annotate(score=Sum('votes__value'))`.

If there is more possible values you can filter annotation by adding `.filter(votes__value__range=(1,1))` to the above query.

If it's more complex you would have to use `extra` with `select`.

Comment: Thank you. How about adding another column which cannot be used with `Sum`, `Avg` and similar? What if we want to add some formatted text or boolean column? `annotate(mycolumn='xxx')` does not work.

Comment: You should use `extra` with `select` here as described there: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#extra

Comment: So, raw SQL is the only way :( Thank you for your help

Answer (score 79):

Raw SQL is *not* the only way. You can use a `Value()` expression (see docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions)):

```
from django.db.models import CharField, Value

MyModel.objects.all().annotate(mycolumn=Value('xxx', output_field=CharField()))
```

Comment: Awesome, I was looking for this

Comment: gives error :  
global name 'IntegerField' is not defined for the output_field

Comment: You need to import [IntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#integerfield) just as you would normally.